# EEA Citizen, moving to the UK with my non-EEA wife - change visa?

Tags: visa, immigration, russia

I am from Portugal, and I plan to move to the UK with my Russian fiancée - we will get married shortly. As I have been reading here and on gov.uk, we will need to apply for an EEA Family Permit; I understand that we can both go together or she can join me there, but we haven't decided about this yet.

The thing is that we plan to do this quite soon, and my fiancée already has a UK Visa that she has obtained in order to work there on business trips, and it is still valid for a further 4 months. So my questions are:

- Should we apply for the EEA Family Permit anyway if we want to move there together (or for her to join me there) after we get married, but before the work Visa expires? OR
- Can we move there with her current work Visa and then go apply for a residence card while we are there?

Thank you for any information or insight you might have on this!

Comment: I would reccomend applying for any relevant permits *before* going there. Life becomes so much easier that way. Also, I'm not sure an airlive will let her board without concrete evidence that she can enter the UK. The business visa may be enough to get her on the flight, but technically, unless she is going there on a business trip for which the visa is meant for, it is not valid for enty into the UK. NEVER LIE. That is a path to disaster.